# Error building a C++ program on Eclipse Indigo

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am a new user of eclipse indigo RS2 under win 7 32 bit
I would like to execute a small program in C or C++ (Hello World).

- I installed the CDT, MinGW, MSYS-1.0.11
- I set the PATH variable (`c:\MinGW\bin` `C:\MinGW\1.0\bin` `C:\MinGW\mingw32\bin`)
- I defined this variable in *window→preferences→C\C++→Build→environment*.
- I create a new project *file→new→C + + Project→exucutable→hello world Project*.

.. gold -> Makefile Project -> hello world project."
builde when the system gives me the following error:

> syntax error hello_world line 7, external location: c: \ mingw \ mingw32 \ bin \ ld.exe: c: \ mingw \ lib \ gcc \ mingw32 \ 4.6.2 \ crtend.o C / C + + Problem "

if I execute the program it gives me

> launch failed. binary not found

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please do not abuse the Caps Lock button.

Comment: How many of those spaces are real?

Comment: `cc: question.c:1:1: expected 'lowercase letter', found 'all-caps bullsheet', bailing out.`

Comment: ccc: missed caps-lock friday buy about 18 hours, dude.

Comment: You probably didn't select the correct toolchain when you made a new project.

Comment: thanks for answer ; can you give me the correct way to made a project

Answer (score 4):

You have to **first build** the project . It will generate binary file under binaries folder. Execute them.